# ASP.NET membership provider database combination with site database

Tags: asp.net, database, membership-provider

i have ASP.NET website with `ASPNETDB.MDF` database from default providor.
i have also MainDB.MDF that contains all other site database.
i want to combine ASPNETDB.MFD into `MainDB.MDF` in order to have only one DB.
is it possible?
if yes what are the disadvantages of this combination?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only theoretical disadvantage is that you may want to run several apps with shared users. Then it would be better to have external provider. Most people don't do that of course then it is better to have data and users in the same database to make deployment and backup easier.

To achieve this just run the asp.net regsql tool against your database and it will create the tables. Then have just one connection string to your database and you are done.